# React-> Why is my react not showing the changes made to state without refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I have a react app that shall show you the length of the state or more like the items within and the thing is it does but it does not do it in real time, it does show you the updated length of the state only after refreshing, there are my home, store and reducer files. My questions are how can I fix this problem, why is it happening, what's causing it and where is it happening?

reducer:

```
import React from 'react'
const reducers=(state={posts:[{}]}, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'post':
            return{
                ...state,
                posts: [...state.posts, {content: action.content}]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default reducers
```

store:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' 

import rootReducer from './reducers'

import logger from 'redux-logger'
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
export const store = createStore(persistedReducer,applyMiddleware(logger))
export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

Home:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import {FaHome, FaBell, FaHashtag,FaUser, FaSearch,FaFeatherAlt} from 'react-icons/fa'
import {AiFillMessage} from 'react-icons/ai'
import {MdSettings} from 'react-icons/md'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {store} from '/Web Dev Projects/React/Amazon Clone/amazonclone/src/store'
import {Navbar, Nav,NavbarBrand, NavItem, FormControl, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './css/Home.css'
import $ from 'jquery'

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        const {posts} = this.props;
        const post=()=>{
            store.dispatch({type:'post', content: 'test post'})
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar bg='white' vraiant='dark'>
                   <NavItem>
                       <span className='homeLink'><FaHome size={25}></FaHome> Home</span>
                       <span className='homeLink'><FaBell size={25}></FaBell> Notifications</span>
                       <span className='homeLink'><FaHashtag size={25}></FaHashtag> Discover</span>
                       <span className='homeLink'><FaUser size={25}></FaUser> Me</span>
                       <span className='messageNotification'><AiFillMessage size={25}></AiFillMessage></span>
                       <span className='settingsButton'><MdSettings size={25}></MdSettings></span>
                       <span className='postButton'><FaFeatherAlt size={25}></FaFeatherAlt></span>


                   </NavItem>
                </Navbar>
                <div className='posts'>
                    <div className='postsHeader'>
                        <p>Posts</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <FormControl className='makePostField'placeholder='make a post'></FormControl>
                        <Button onClick={()=>post().val())}>Post</Button>
                        {posts.length}
                        {posts.map(post=><div>{post.content}</div>)}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps=(state={posts:[{}]})=>{
    return{
        posts: state.posts
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

Comment: What actions are dispatched, do they have the correct value and do they change the state correctly. I don't see anywhere in your question where you dispatch something that would trigger `case 'post':` in your question.

Comment: Actually I found the solution like 30 minutes ago, thing was that my  store and reducer were outside of the components folder, odd.